# Static code analysis puzzler in extremely simple declaration

Tags: static-analysis, parasoft

```
myNameSpace::myEnumType LookupEnumValueFromString(const std::string& theString)
{
    myEnumType ReturnVal = myNameSpace::myEnumType::eUNKNOWN;
```

Parasoft reports “Implicit conversion of integer type from wider to narrower type shall not be used” on the assignment to `myEnumType`.

Where

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    
    enum class myEnumType : uint32_t
    {
        ....  // other values
        eUNKNOWN = 0xFFFFFFFF
    }
```

and

```
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;
```

If I redefine eUNKNOWN to be 0x7FFFFFFF, the report goes away. But the enum type is unsigned, so why does this happen? I am sure that I am overlooking something very obvious, but what?

Comment: `eUNKNOWN = 0xFFFFFFFF` is signed (by default) - add the little U on the end should solve this?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't someone already posted this is an answer, but then deleted it, so you weren't to know. Thanks for the suggestion, though (+1).